# jest + enzyme shallow .simulate('change',[args]) not passing args to function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with the following props and method:

```
class OrderDish extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        order: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        addCommentToOrder: React.PropTypes.func,
    };

    handleCommentChange = (event) => {
        this.props.addCommentToOrder(event.target.value, this.props.order, false);
    };

    render() {
        const { order, canOrder } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="Order-dish">
                        <TextField
                            className='Order-dish-comment'
                            ref="comment"
                            id={order.entry.type}
                            value={order.comment ? order.comment : ''}
                            onChange={this.handleCommentChange}
                            fullWidth
                            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
                            disabled={!canOrder}
                        />
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default OrderDish;
```

Now I want to test that the `handleCommentChange` function gets called with the right arguments when the `onChange` event triggers on the `TextField`.

I have a separate test for the method itself which works as expected:

```
it('handleCommentChange should call addCommentToOrder passing event.target.value, this.props.order, false', () => {
    const mockKeyPressFN = jest.fn((input) => {return input});
    let orderDish = shallow(<OrderDish order={mockOrder} addCommentToOrder={mockKeyPressFN}/>);

    orderDish.instance().handleCommentChange({key: 'Enter', target: {value: 'mock'}});
    expect(mockKeyPressFN.mock.calls[0]).toContainEqual("mock", {"entry": {"name": "blah", "tag": "MAIN", "type": "bleh"}, "price": 5.44}, false);
  });
```

Now when I try to do the same with [simulate](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html) (pass the mock object, see if the function gets called):

```
it('TextField should call handleCommentChange onChange', ()=> {
    const mockKeyPressFN = jest.fn();
    let orderDish = shallow(<OrderDish order={mockOrder} addCommentToOrder={mockKeyPressFN}/>);
    let textField = orderDish.find('TextField');
    let event = {key: 'Enter', target: {value: 'mock'}};

    textField.simulate('change',[event]);
    expect(mockKeyPressFN.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

I get:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

So I guess my `event` object is not getting passed correctly to the `.simulate` function?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try textField.simulate('change', event); and stick some debugging logs in to see where it's failing

Comment: Just figured this out, works without passing args as an array

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the array.

`textField.simulate('change',[event]);`

will be

`textField.simulate('change',event);`

Another way of doing it is:

```
act(() => {
  orderDish.find('TextField').simulate('change', {key: 'Enter', target: {value: 'mock'}}, other_arguments_to_handleCommentChange);
  orderDish.update();
});
```